# I need a term for a historical person

Tags: single-word-requests

I need the term for a historical person who made a change, and now cannot live a free life. Like, once they make a change, they will be needed by many others, which limits him/her to take a time off where he doesnt need to keep working in order to help.
Im trying to use this info as an example.
(Im not sure if the questions is clear enough :/)

Comment: Do you think this is about English language and usage?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about English, but about history.

Comment: Not historical, but the protagonist of the movie "It's a Wonderful Life."

Comment: http://history.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Regarding language, I suggest the phrase *prisoner of circumstance*.

Comment: I have (hopefully) clarified the question as an English language question, and suggest that it NOT be closed.

Answer (score 2):

On such term is ["prisoner of circumstance."](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/prisoner%20of%20circumstance) This person has been trapped by his (probably) good deeds, and now lives a life that is circumscribed by his former actions.

Note: stevesliva apparently posted a comment (not an answer) with a similar response at about the same time as me. I don't know whether I saw his comment, or answered independently, or our answers "cross in the (e)mail."

Comment: @stevesliva: OK I posted mine about the time you posted yours. But thank you.

Comment: I don't really mind...  maybe throw me an *as mentioned in the comments* in the future.

Comment: @stevesliva: I don't honestly remember whether I saw yours first or came to the same thing independentl  (I don't usually read comments.)  If you want the credit, answer it yourself, because I do read others' answers. But I edited my answer to acknowledge you.

Comment: I usually do a Ctrl-F on whatever word I'm going to suggest because more often than not I do not notice that someone else suggests it as a synonym in their own answer.  But I actually agree that being scooped in that way-- a previous comment or passing reference in another answer-- by no means says you shouldn't make it an answer.  I just think it raises the bar for substantive content in the answer.  I think part of the reason I'm poking at you here is because your answer was a one-liner.